# Acer "Empowerment" Backup

Tags: acer-aspire

I need to learn how the Acer "Empowerment" backup actually works.

Brought in today in August: The customer had done a complete backup in January, with incremental backups almost every week or two since. Something went wonky over the weekend, so he performed a restore from his last backup in June. Well, his financial data in Quickbooks is only restored to January, and I can't see a reason for it.

It appears that he's done everything correctly, but not being very well versed in the nuances of the Acer Backup Manager, I'm not sure if a mistake was made.  Where can I find out?

While I don't have the exact model number handy, I can tell you this is a Mid-Level Aspire Model with Vista Home Premium and 2 GB RAM.  The restore data seems to live on a partition named "Data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Google Search](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=011769461964377083690%3Af7atrlze_g8&ie=UTF-8&q=acer+backup&sa=) would seem to suggest that NTI makes an OEM version of its Backup Now for Acer. Perhaps going to NTI's support pages or FAQ might find you the manual etc that you need.